# Pesquisa filtrando Data Inicial e Final Yii

Tags: php, mysqli, yii

Como realiza uma pesquisa da Data Inicial e Data Final. Estou usando o Framework Yii. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Não estou conseguindo pesquisar a data de forma correta.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

https://github.com/maurodenison/Yii-Framework/blob/master/basic2/views/sale-items/index.php

Comment: Tem como postar o código do que já fez?

Comment: Sem os Models que estão sendo usados para esse formulário e o model da tabela em questão, fica difícil passar uma resposta precisa.

Comment: Você conseguiu resolver Mauro?

Comment: Sim @durtto, como posso finalizar este assunto?

Comment: Crie uma resposta, por menor que seja, mostrando como você fez para resolver. Assim poderá ajudar outras pessoas.